# How to change whole Datatable background color using jQuery not depending on any column or row value

Tags: jquery, datatables

Simple but I am not being able to change this table background color. I am binding datatable using jQuery ajax call. Any help will be good.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                data: { Alert: true },
                url: '/GunTracking/GetGunAlertsList',
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    var table = $('#GunTracking-detail-datatable').DataTable();
                    table.clear().draw();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var id = data[i].GunId;                         
                        var remarks = '<button type="button" title="Remarks" class="btn btn-xs  btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gun-tracking-remark-popup"  onclick="javascript: OpenRemarks ('+id +')" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>';
                        var rowNode = table.row.add([
                            //data[i].GunId,
                            data[i].BranchName,
                            data[i].GunSerialNo,
                            data[i].GunTypeName,
                            data[i].ModelNo,
                            data[i].CarriedBy,
                            data[i].Bullets,
                            data[i].Purpose,
                            data[i].IssueDate,
                            data[i].IssueTime,
                            data[i].TotalEstimatedTime,
                            remarks,
                        ]);
                    }                        
                    table.draw();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you point to the URL you are trying to do this and elaborate a little on what you have tried so far?

Comment: In URL i am giving controller jsonResult  method path. My ques is while binding this datatable how to give background color for all rows.

Comment: I mean, could you upload this on a public URL, fiddle or codepen so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing something like this CSS should do the trick:

```
#GunTracking-detail-datatable{
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

If you really want to go to town and alter the whole of the stuff DataTables gives you'd need to have something like this:

```
#GunTracking-detail-datatable_wrapper{
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Hope that helps, example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/m6q4jc4j/2/).